# C - How to count exact word in a string? (exluding the times the word is inside of another)

Tags: c, string, cpu-word

I'm making a program which reads from stdin or from a file and counts number of if statements. I've done it but if for example I have a variable called "asdifasd" or "ifasd" it shall be counted as an if statement. How do I extract solely the if-statements? Here's my code:

```
char str[150];
int ifs = 0;

while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        char *p = str;
        while (((p = (strstr(p, "if"))) != NULL)) {
            ifs++;
            ++p;
        }
    }
```

I've been thinking about doing something with `strncmp` but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue - the code will count all 'if' even in the middle of a word, just as you want it??

Comment: Tell us, what are the obvious differences between `ifasd` and `if (asd)`? How can you use that to solve your problem?

Comment: No mate, I want it to count the if-statements only. I DON'T want it to count like "int qweif = 0;" as an if-statement.

Comment: @kaylum I tried counting "if(" and "if " but I gues I didn't know how to make and it failed

Comment: Well, then show us that attempt. We can't tell you what you did wrong there unless you show us that code.

Comment: This is an extremely naive approach to parsing. What if you find a commented `if`, or text comments that contain the very frequent English word *"if"*? Looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Hadn't thought about that. Wow! That is getting very heavy :D.
@kaylum I made two while loops, one checking for "if " and the other for "if(" and I think it worked. But also found another way - to make sure that the "if" is not surrounded by anything (isalnum). I guess one of these techniques shall work for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've found "if" using strstr, check the characters immediately before and after to make sure they're not a letter. Like:

```
{
  char *p = str;
  while (((p = (strstr(p, "if"))) != NULL)) {
    if ((p == str || !isalnum((unsigned char) p[-1])) &&
         !isalnum((unsigned char) p[2]))
      ++ifs;
    ++p;
  }
}
```

Comment: "make sure they're not a letter". That is not sufficient. For example, underscore (`_`) is not a letter yet it is a valid character in a variable name.

Comment: Surely it's trivial to tailor my example to include underscore in the definition of "word".

Comment: Surely it is trivial to write an answer  that fully and accurately addresses the problem?

Comment: @Waxrat thank you! It works. What I tried was to make two while loops, one searching for "if " and the other searching for "if(" but I think it still had some flaws. I think your solution works better.